# Error when concatenating js libraries (underscore,moment, etc)

Tags: javascript, concatenation, momentjs

I am trying to concatenate (without uglify!) all vendor libraries like underscore.js, moment.js and so on into one single file vendor.js. At the moment the libs are loaded with normal script tags which works as intended. when concatenate the libs I get the following error:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value)(...).call is not a function
```

the problem only occurs for libs that are the defined as follows:

```
(function (undefined) { ... }).call(this);
```

is there a way to overcome this problem without excluding those libs from the concat process?

Comment: are you using _requirejs_?

Comment: i am not using requirejs and i would like to avoid an additional lib.

Answer (score 1):

ok the problem was another script (SlexAxton/messageformat.js) where I included the locales directly in the build process. the locale is defined without an semicolon at the end and this produced the mentioned error.

Comment: I had exactly this problem with **gulp-concat** and **gulp-uglify**, where the IIFE from the preceding script was defined as `(function () {...}())`, without the trailing semicolon. Adding the semicolon, as in `(function () {...}());`, fixed it.